# Flutter How to display JSON response on Listview

Tags: flutter, api, listview

I want to display JSON data on Listview when I do button click, I can print valid JSON data on console so I want a way to show it on a listview, I am still a beginner in Flutter, your help will be appreaciated.

My model class

```
class Vehicle {
  int? id;
  int? sourceId;
  int? serviceId;
  int? categoryId;
  String? category;
  String? description;
  dynamic value;
  int? serviceResponsePropertyId;
  int? mappingId;
  bool? isVisible;
  int? packageRequestId;
  int? sortOrder;

  Vehicle(
      {required this.id,
      required this.sourceId,
      required this.serviceId,
      required this.categoryId,
      required this.category,
      required this.description,
      required this.value,
      required this.serviceResponsePropertyId,
      required this.mappingId,
      required this.isVisible,
      required this.packageRequestId,
      required this.sortOrder});

  Vehicle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    sourceId = json['SourceId'];
    serviceId = json['ServiceId'];
    categoryId = json['CategoryId'];
    category = json['Category'];
    description = json['Description'];
    value = json['Value'];
    serviceResponsePropertyId = json['ServiceResponsePropertyId'];
    mappingId = json['MappingId'];
    isVisible = json['IsVisible'];
    packageRequestId = json['PackageRequestId'];
    sortOrder = json['SortOrder'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    data['Id'] = id;
    data['SourceId'] = sourceId;
    data['ServiceId'] = serviceId;
    data['CategoryId'] = categoryId;
    data['Category'] = category;
    data['Description'] = description;
    data['Value'] = value;
    data['ServiceResponsePropertyId'] = serviceResponsePropertyId;
    data['MappingId'] = mappingId;
    data['IsVisible'] = isVisible;
    data['PackageRequestId'] = packageRequestId;
    data['SortOrder'] = sortOrder;
    return data;
  }
}
```

JSON response

```
[
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "AdjustedValues",
        "Value": [],
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 474,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 475,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "CarId",
        "Value": 120354,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 100,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Year",
        "Value": 2017,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 103,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 6
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Full Model Description",
        "Value": "2017 AUDI A3 Sedan 1.0T FSI S tronic [2016-2017]",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 104,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Model",
        "Value": "A3 Sedan 1.0T FSI S tronic [2016-2017]",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 105,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 5
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ImageUrl",
        "Value": "https://cdn.lightstoneauto.co.za/PHOTOS/AUDI/120354_1_Z7.jpg",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 107,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Make",
        "Value": "AUDI",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 110,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 3
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Type",
        "Value": "AUDI A3 Sedan",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 111,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 4
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 125,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 7,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 126,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 9999
    },
    {
        "CarId": 0,
        "SpecCategory": "General",
        "Id": -1,
        "SourceId": -1,
        "ServiceId": 7,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Body shape",
        "Value": "Sedan",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 320,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 9999
    },
    {
        "CarId": 0,
        "SpecCategory": "General",
        "Id": -6,
        "SourceId": -6,
        "ServiceId": 7,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Drive type",
        "Value": "4x2",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 154,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 9999
    },
    {
        "CarId": 0,
        "SpecCategory": "General",
        "Id": -7,
        "SourceId": -7,
        "ServiceId": 7,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Fuel type",
        "Value": "Petrol",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 153,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 9999
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "LastFiveSales",
        "Value": [
            {
                "SaleId": 701436,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-06-24T14:09:04Z",
                "SalePrice": 289900.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "CITY OF TSHWANE",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "SaleId": 698229,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-06-09T15:30:38Z",
                "SalePrice": 299900.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "CITY OF TSHWANE",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "SaleId": 695530,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-05-30T13:24:17Z",
                "SalePrice": 289995.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "CITY OF TSHWANE",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "SaleId": 685020,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-04-14T12:27:37Z",
                "SalePrice": 366948.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "EMFULENI",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "SaleId": 683843,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-04-11T15:00:38Z",
                "SalePrice": 315500.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "UMHLATHUZE",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            }
        ],
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 481,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 482,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Auction",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "SourceId": 1,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Auction Estimate",
        "Value": 189400.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 494,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Cost",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 2,
        "SourceId": 2,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Cost Estimate",
        "Value": 238300.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 495,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Cost",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 3,
        "SourceId": 3,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Cost Estimate High",
        "Value": 259800.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 496,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 3
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Cost",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 4,
        "SourceId": 4,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Cost Estimate Low",
        "Value": 218700.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 497,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 2
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Retail",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 5,
        "SourceId": 5,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Retail Estimate",
        "Value": 300800.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 498,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Retail",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 6,
        "SourceId": 6,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Retail Estimate High",
        "Value": 327900.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 499,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 3
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Retail",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 7,
        "SourceId": 7,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Retail Estimate Low",
        "Value": 276000.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 500,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 2
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Trade",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 8,
        "SourceId": 8,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Trade Estimate",
        "Value": 261300.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 501,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Trade",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 9,
        "SourceId": 9,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Trade Estimate High",
        "Value": 284900.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 502,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 3
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Trade",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 10,
        "SourceId": 10,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Trade Estimate Low",
        "Value": 239800.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 503,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13870410,
        "SortOrder": 2
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 7,
        "Category": "Report",
        "Description": "ReportUrl",
        "Value": "https://pdf.lightstoneauto.co.za/Index.aspx?sourceurl=https://cdn.lightstoneauto.co.za/REPORTS/LIVE/f1a817b0-6b13-479a-b667-19d4ecd65a65.html",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 0,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 7,
        "Category": "Report",
        "Description": "HtmlUrl",
        "Value": "https://cdn.lightstoneauto.co.za/REPORTS/LIVE/f1a817b0-6b13-479a-b667-19d4ecd65a65.html",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 0,
        "SortOrder": 0
    }
]
```

I want to only show certain items in the list,which are in "Value" like model, year, model etc..

My API function

```
Future<List<Vehicle>?> signInData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? token = prefs.getString('token');

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post('$_baseUrl/api/gateway',
          data: {
            "ClientPackageId": "0cdd231a-d7ad-4a68-a934-d373affb5100",
            "PlatformId": "ios",
            "ClientUserId": "AhmedOmar",
            "VinNumber": VINumber
          },
          options: Options(
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
              "Charset": 'utf-8',
              "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
            },
          ));
      print("data is here");
      print(json.encode(response.data));
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("decoded");

        final parsedJson = json.decode(json.encode(response.data));
        print(
            List<Vehicle>.from(parsedJson.map((job) => Vehicle.fromJson(job))));
        return List<Vehicle>.from(
            parsedJson.map((job) => Vehicle.fromJson(job)));
      } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        // call your refresh token api here and save it in shared preference
        print(response.statusCode);
        await getToken();
        signInData();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load data');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(text),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3), //default is 4s
    );
    // Find the Scaffold in the widget tree and use it to show a SnackBar.
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

The results I want to achieve is below, shown in a picture
[image]

Comment: Please always include any textual output (data, errors,...) as actual text within your question rather than embedding screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :   `List<Vehicle> _vehicleList;`

instead of return statement write :

```
_vehicleList = List<Vehicle>.from(
            parsedJson.map((job) => Vehicle.fromJson(job)));
```

and then after `setState((){});`

and I hope that you have `ListView` is available inside `Build` method

```
ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text($_vehicleList[index].category),
              Text($_vehicleList[index].value),
            ],
          );
        },
        itemCount: _vehicleList.length)
```

Comment: Hi @HardikMehta where should I do this List<Vehicle> _vehicleList;  in the API function method or in the lisview class?

Comment: signInData() you have inside that you have to assign like that : _vehicleList = List<Vehicle>.from(
            parsedJson.map((job) => Vehicle.fromJson(job)));\